# Why won't this image display in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class app(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        image = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
        Label(image=image).pack()

window = app()
window.mainloop()
```

When I run the above code, the image is not displayed. However, when I run the following code...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
Label(image=image).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

...the image does show up. Why is this and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
image = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
Label(image=image).pack()
```

with:

```
self.image = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
Label(image=self.image).pack()
```

The image reference needs not to be garbage collected in order to be displayed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Are there any other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: @MilanTom There can be a number of ways of solving. The key idea being _keepinng_ the reference to the image object available in the scope which the image is shown. In the case above, it is the global scope.